# New to bash scripting, writing wget script

Tags: bash, wget

This is the first time I have ever tried to code anything, and now I would like some help.

I get a syntax error, but don't know where it is. Can you please look at my code and tell me what I need to fix the syntax, and what I need to improve this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Please Input Website To Get URLS and IPs" 

while read line do wget $line -O $line.txt -o /dev/null ls -l $line.txt

grep "href=" $line.txt | cat -d"/" -f3 |grep $line |sort -u > $line-srv.txt

for hostname in $(cat $line-srv.txt);do host $hostname |grep "has adress"

done
```

Comment: Please include the specific error you get. Also please indent your code cleanly (one additional level of indentation for each control block) and you might find your error.

Comment: It may not be possible as you're missing the other end of your while loop i.e. where's the other `done`?

Comment: @EtanReisner 
i will try the indentation 
specific error: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @konsolebox 

to be true - i don't know :P i thought it was supposed to look like that haha :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a 2nd "done".  You have only terminated one of your while loops.

Consistent indentation would catch this.  That is, if you indent everything within your loop, then it would be much more obvious that something is missing.  E.g.

```
echo -e "Please Input Website To Get URLS and IPs" 

while read line
do
     wget $line -O $line.txt -o /dev/null
     ls -l $line.txt

     grep "href=" $line.txt | cat -d"/" -f3 |grep $line |sort -u > $line-srv.txt

     for hostname in $(cat $line-srv.txt);do
        host $hostname |grep "has adress"
     done
```

Comment: A good answer. That said, if trying to demonstrate best practices, one should probably add quoting where appropriate here, and take out some undesirable practices (such as the unnecessary use of `echo -e`).

Comment: aah!  I think I got it! Thank you so much! :D 

gotta learn the right indentation though! hah

Comment: Do look at the comments posted by Charles Duffy as they call out other functional flaws in the script.

Comment: i have taken a look at his comments too, and reading as i speak :-) 

@EJK 
ps: i will try and run your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p "Please Input Website To Get URLS and IP (CTRL-D to exit): " TARGET || { echo >&2; false; }; do
    wget -O - -o "/dev/null" "$TARGET" | grep -Po '(?<=://)[^/]+' | grep "$TARGET"
done | sort -u | xargs -r host | grep 'has address'
```

Try to run it and give a comment about how your expected function compares to it.

Or another form:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p "Please Input Website To Get URLS and IP (CTRL-D to exit): " TARGET || { echo >&2; false; }; do
    wget -O - -o "/dev/null" "$TARGET" | grep -Po '(?<=://)[^/]+' | grep "$TARGET" | sort -u | xargs -r host | grep 'has address'
done
```

Comment: im a total newb right now! :D

but i can only get yours to loop:
"Please Input Website To Get URLS and IP (CTRL-D to exit): "
every time i enter a webiste :P

Comment: @LucidTruth Well your original code wants to accept multiple websites.